# amazon linux 2 の /etc/fstab を設定する際に、インスタンスタイプが変わっても動作するようにさせることはできる？

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

amazon linux 2 で、ルートボリューム以外を常時アタッチする場合、そのマウント情報を `/etc/fstab` に記述することになるかと思います。

fstab の記述方法についてざっと調べると、基本的に `/dev` 以下のフルパスを指定してマウントする指示が書いてある場合が多いです。しかし、各 ec2 ボリュームがアタッチされた際に作成される `/dev` 以下のパスは、インスタンスタイプが変われば変化します。 （例: t2 系: `/dev/xvdf`, t3 系: `/dev/nvme1n1`)

#### 質問

- aws のボリュームの fstab にてマウントする場合に、インスタンスタイプが変化しても(つまり、 `/dev` 以下のパスが変わっても)正しくマウントできるように設定する方法などはありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWSについては詳しくありませんが、マウント時にデバイス名が変わってしまう場合の一般的な対応としては`/etc/fstab`で`UUID`を指定してマウントする方法があります。

**関連しそうなAWSのマニュアル**

- [EBS デバイスの特定](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/nvme-ebs-volumes.html#identify-nvme-ebs-device)
- [再起動後に接続ボリュームを自動的にマウントする](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html#ebs-mount-after-reboot)